Excel concatenate advice for combining rows into a single field for jira bulk upload
I have a bit of a random question. I'm trying to convert hundreds of steps out of silk into Jira stories and sub-tasks. Unfortunately the export I've gotten is very unwieldy and is proving to be harder than I first expected.
CSV Structure:



Parent (story)
Test Name (sub-task)
Step Name
Action
Result




Big Test 1
Test 1
Step 1
Do this thing
Outcome




Step 2
Do this next thing
Outcome




Step 3
Do this other thing
Outcome


Big Test 1
Test 2
Step 1
Do this thing
Outcome




Step 2
Do this thing
Outcome


Big Test 2
Test 1
Step 1
Do this thing
Outcome




Step 2
Do this thing
Outcome



Etc. this goes on for a while. The number of Test Names to Big Test is variable as is the number of steps per test.
What I'm wanting is to get a description column that will double as the Description in Jira that is pre-formatted
eg
Parent = Story summary
Test Name = Sub-task summary attached to story
Description =



Step Name
Action
Result




Step 1
Do this thing
Outcome


Step 2
Do this next thing
Outcome


Step 3
Do this other thing
Outcome



I've tried adding multiple columns into the source table and using a concatenate to get to somewhat of the structure I need but I can't figure out a way to do it without adding heaps of columns to add the previous value above it.
I extended the Test Name down so its the same for each of the steps.
The most working thought I've got at the moment is along the lines of:
="||"&[Step Name]&"||"&[Action]&"||"&[Result]&"||"&char(10)

To return:
||Step 1 ||Do this thing ||Outcome || 

Then using an IF to check if the test name is the same as the row above and then concatenate those together but I can only get this to work for 2 rows. I've then had to add columns to check if there is to be another row etc. which is... not great.
I know I'm missing something somewhere that will make this easier. Any advice will be appreciated even if its just pointing me in the right direction. I had serious issues trying to google what I meant. Ideally I don't want to be creating these items individually as it will be a nightmare.
I am investigating trying something with a pivot and then going from there but struggling with that too.
I know this is probably worded bad but its the best I could describe it

For some reason my table formatting isn't working but when I open it to edit it its displaying as a table. Unsure on how to fix this

I'm not quite sure what you want to do but I am quite sure that you want to do it with PowerQuery.

Can you at least post a screenshot of your desired format?

Honestly, I am not sure what you want to do either. but I think you want description for each story to be a string (rather than a table as in your question, but since you didn't create that markdown yourself, so probably better to clear that up with a screenshot)
If you have MS365, you can use below:

=LET(
    descriptions, C2:C8 & "||" & D2:D8 & "||" & E2:E8,
    stories, SCAN("", A2:A8, LAMBDA(a, v, IF(v = "", a, v))),
    sub_tasks, SCAN("", B2:B8, LAMBDA(a, v, IF(v = "", a, v))),
    unique_stories_and_tasks, UNIQUE(HSTACK(stories, sub_tasks), FALSE, FALSE),
    grouped, BYROW(
        unique_stories_and_tasks,
        LAMBDA(x,
            LET(
                story, INDEX(x, 1, 1),
                sub_task, INDEX(x, 1, 2),
                filtered, FILTER(descriptions, (stories = story) * (sub_tasks = sub_task), ""),
                TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), TRUE, filtered)
            )
        )
    ),
    HSTACK(unique_stories_and_tasks, grouped)
)

=C2:C8 & "||" & D2:D8 & "||" & E2:E8 concatenates step name, action and result.
=SCAN("", A2:A8, LAMBDA(a, v, IF(v = "", a, v))) fills in the blank row in story column.
=SCAN("", B2:B8, LAMBDA(a, v, IF(v = "", a, v))) fills in the blank row in sub task column.
Then the main grouping logic is in BYROW:
For each story + sub task, it filters out the relevant steps(or descriptions), and concatenates them with char(10)

This is absolutely bang on what I'm after, I've made a few tweaks and its absolutely perfect. I'd never thought about using LETs in a formula. I've used variables in macros and SQL but hadn't thought about using them for this. Will make my life easier going forward.
Thanks for somehow deciphering what I was after.

You are welcome! Yes, LET and LAMBDA make excel almost feel like python. but if you are familiar with SQL, you might end up liking power query.

You indicate CSV structure in your question.
Assuming your data is coming from a CSV file, I suggest using Power Query (available in Excel since 2010) to access and manipulate the data.

Data=>from Text/CSV
Select the csv file
Select the Transform option
Select the Advanced Editor
Paste the code below into the Advanced Editor

Change the file name in the Source line to whatever your actual file name is.



Explore the Applied Steps and read the notes within the code to understand the algorithm.
`Close and Load to write the results to a worksheet
let

//Replace file name in next step with your actual full file path
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\Documents\for Jira.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=5, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
 
//Set data type to text
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",
        List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Promoted Headers"), each {_, type nullable text})),

//Replace blanks with nulls in the first two columns
//   could extend this to other columns if necessary
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type1","",null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Parent (story)", "Test Name (sub-task)"}),

//Fill Down to fill in the nulls, then merge the columns
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Replaced Value",{"Parent (story)", "Test Name (sub-task)"}),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Filled Down",
        Table.ColumnNames(#"Filled Down"),Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("||", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),

//Add || at beginning and end
    #"Add ||" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Merged Columns",{{"Merged", each "||" & _ & "||", type text}})
in
    #"Add ||"

CSV File
Parent (story),Test Name (sub-task),Step Name,Action,Result
Big Test 1,Test 1,Step 1,Do this thing,Outcome
,,Step 2,Do this next thing,Outcome
,,Step 3,Do this other thing,Outcome
Big Test 1,Test 2,Step 1,Do this thing,Outcome
,,Step 2,Do this thing,Outcome
Big Test 2,Test 1,Step 1,Do this thing,Outcome
,,Step 2,Do this thing,Outcome

Result

